# Extend CreatesUserForm and keep l10n / i18n built-in feature

Tags: python, django, forms, localization, internationalization

I am discovering **Django** (`v2.1.1`) and want to set up a *signin page* in which I have 2 emails fields, if the 2 fields are identical, I call `form.is_valid()`.

The *project tree* :

```
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── project
│       │   └── home.html
│       └── registration
│           ├── logged_out.html
│           ├── login.html
│           └── signin.html
└── app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
    ├── migrations
    └── templates
        └── app
            └── home.html
```

Internationalization config in `project/settings.py` :

```
# (…)
# Internationalization
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-fr'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
# (…)
```

---

With a *basic django signin view* it **works well**:

`project/views.py` :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'project/home.html', {'context':'project index'})

def signin(request):
    # (…)
    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signin.html', {'form': form})
```

I have a nice *French translated* HTML form (except for the `submit button`) :

[image: Django basic signin form]

---

Let's add an `email` field in the form, `email` is a built-in user fields (as `first_name` & `last_name`) so I just add a new class `SignInForm` inheriting from `UserCreationForm` :

`project/forms.py` :

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignInForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

I update `project/views.py` :

```
# (…)
from project.forms import SignInForm
# (…)
def signin(request):
    # (…)
    form = SignInForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signin.html', {'form': form})
```

**It works** : a nice *French translated field* is added but it do not have a `help_text` attribute :

[image: Django signin form with additionnal email field]

---

**Now I'm stuck…**

If I want to set the attribute `'required': True` to the `email` field (it is required and I want to show a translated `help_text`). The only way I found is overriding the built-in email field, but I loose translation and it do not shows the `help_text` :

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class SignInForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

[image]

If I add a second `email2` field, I was hoping copy the original `User.email` with something like `email2 = User.email`, but it looks like this is not the good place were email is stored. I can use `forms.EmailField()` as above, but I'd really like to take benefit of the built-in translation.

---

**Then here is my questions** :

How to use an `email` field with *build in attributes* (name, required, help_text, …) and get translations ? (When I have an answer I assume that I will found the way to do the same with the `submit`, `first_name` & `last_name`)

Can I duplicate the email field with this constraint? (I do not want to store this second field, just checking before calling `form.is_valid()`)

_

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things at play here.

The `UserCreationForm` is a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), which derives its field from a model. In this case, the model is your current [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) setting. When the `email` form field is created, it inspects the corresponding `email` field from the model, where it will find the `help_text` which is wrapped in a [`gettext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext) (or `gettext_lazy`) call to allow for i18n to work, as well as any other attribute.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to duplicate the `email` form field to override some (if any) attributes and to allow you to validate it against the original one. While Django makes it a little harder than what you tried because it is using [metaclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) to generate the form class, there has been a public API for doing just that since version 1.8: [get_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_field)

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
class SignInForm(UserCreationForm):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignInForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        email_field = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL._meta.get_field('email')
        self.fields['email2'] = email_field.formfield()
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['email2'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
        fields = (...)
```

A few of remarks:

- Using `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead of just `User` will save you from changing the reference to `User` in your entire codebase should you switch to a custom user model.
- `get_field` also has a plural form (see docs) to retrieve multiple fields at the same time.
- In general, any runtime modifications of forms (overriding field attributes, etc.) happens in the `__init__` method, since it's where you first get the 'real' form after Django does its black magic with metaclasses, see the `required` 
  attribute override.
- If you want to override a translatable text, you will have to go through `gettext` and learn about this mechanism if you want to do it properly. You could of course just hardcode it in French. ;)
- **Edit:** Form validation happens in the `validate` and `validate_{field}` form methods, triggered by `is_valid`. You don't have to have this logic inside the view.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Lots of things in there, thanks. I will try soon and give feedback.